# how to setup AucTex with LuaTex in Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex

How can I add to the list LuaTeX when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>?

I was able to add Latexmk to the list by adding

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push 
    '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
      :help "Run Latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
```

What would be the `/.emacs` entry for LuaTeX?

Or is there a way to bind switching to the LuaTeX?  For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>.

Comment: If you use latexmk you can tell it to use luatex.

Comment: @N.N. How?  I only went to call LuaTeX for a few compilation most are pdflatex so I don't want every run to be LuaTex.